# highlight only screen line in vim?

Tags: vim

Highlighting the CursorLine is easy, but is there a way to highlight only the actual screen line when the real line is long enough to wrap at least once? When the line is a full paragraph of prose, highlighting the whole thing is of limited use.

Answer (score 0):

The <kbd>g</kbd>+movement commands operate on screen lines instead of real lines, so <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>g</kbd><kbd>$</kbd> will move the cursor to the start of the screen line, turn on visual selection and select to the end of the screen line.

Comment: That works for one-off cases, but I'm looking for something I can set and leave.

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be no way to do this. Instead, here's what I went with. I added the following to my vimrc file:

```
autocmd FileType markdown set formatoptions=ant
autocmd FileType markdown set textwidth=72
autocmd FileType text set formatoptions-=t
```

This way, in markdown and *only* in markdown, each screen line is a true line, but they readjust automagically.

For the highlighting itself, I've found the following useful for the Solarized dark colorscheme:

```
hi CursorLine guifg=White guibg=#012228 ctermfg=White ctermbg=24
```

Instead of a lighter background color for the cursor line, it gives a lighter foreground color. In other words, higher contrast, not lower. It's subtle, but effective.

Answer (score 0):

As of Vim patch [8.1.2029](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v8.1.2029) the (quite new) ['cursorlineopt'](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#'cursorlineopt') setting has been amended to allow for a screenline highlighting of the cursorline highlighting. This was based on a quite old patch of mine but has been completely reworked.